# Cannot get Screenshot using Android Espresso TestFramework

Tags: android, unit-testing, functional-testing, android-testing, android-espresso

Getting the path as of following but cannot access the screenshot, any idea?

```
Brings up path : /storage/emulated/0/test-screenshots/screenshot-001.png
```

while using the method:

Trying to capture a screenshot using the following method in Android Espresso:

```
takeScreenshot("screenshot-001", getActivity()); 

public static void takeScreenshot(String name, Activity activity)
   {
    // In Testdroid Cloud, taken screenshots are always stored
    // under /test-screenshots/ folder and this ensures those screenshots
    // be shown under Test Results
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/test-screenshots/" + name + ".png";
    Log.d("Logs", "Image Path is " + path);
    View scrView = activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
    scrView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scrView.getDrawingCache());
    scrView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    OutputStream out = null;
    File imageFile = new File(path);

    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
    } catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
        // exception
    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
        // exception
    } finally {

        try {
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception exc) {
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Do you have permission to store on sdcard in your application?

Comment: Yes it seems like I can see the photo.png on the adb shell in above folder but cannot pull to machine using adb

Comment: What command did you use?